# How to configure ARA for Ansible on Ubuntu + Apache2.4 + mod_wsgi?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, mod-wsgi, wsgi, apache2.4

I'm trying to install ARA (https://github.com/openstack/ara) on an Ubuntu 16.04 to monitor my Ansible playbook executions.

I follow carefully the documentation (http://ara.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webserver.html#debian-ubuntu) but every time that I test I'm be redirected to http://ara.home.lab/about

Here are my configuration files:

Apache Vhost:

```
cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/ara.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Replace ServerName by your hostname
    ServerName ara.home.lab

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ara-error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ara-access.log combined

    WSGIDaemonProcess ara user=www-data group=www-data processes=4 threads=1
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/ara/ara-wsgi

    SetEnv ANSIBLE_CONFIG /var/www/ara/ansible.cfg

    <Directory /var/www/ara>
        WSGIProcessGroup ara
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Ansible Configuration File:

```
cat /var/www/ara/ansible.cfg
[defaults]
# This directory is required to store temporary files for Ansible and ARA
local_tmp = /var/www/ara/.ansible/tmp

[ara]
# This will default the database and logs location to be inside that directory.
dir = /var/www/ara/.ara
```

Vhost Directory:

```
$ pwd
/var/www/ara
$ ls -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 4 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 12 00:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root     root     4096 Mar 11 23:59 ..
drwxrwx--- 3 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 27 17:00 .ansible
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  234 Oct 27 16:57 ansible.cfg
drwx------ 2 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 12 00:15 .ara
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 1804 Mar 11 01:08 ara-wsgi
```

So far I'm not able to find any log from the application that is telling me something wrong.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration looks fine but you're missing the bit where you tell Ansible that it needs to load the ARA callback plugin and where it is located.

To find where ARA is, you can run the following command which works regardless if you're running python2 or python3:

```
$ python -c "import os,ara; print(os.path.dirname(ara.__file__))"
```

If ARA is installed in a virtual environment, you'll need to source and activate it before running that command.

If it works, it should print something like this:

```
# The path for your ARA package might be different than this
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ara
```

To enable ARA as an Ansible callback plugin, add this path to the callback_plugins configuration in ansible.cfg:

```
[defaults]
# This directory is required to store temporary files for Ansible and ARA
local_tmp = /var/www/ara/.ansible/tmp
callback_plugins = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ara/plugins/callbacks

[ara]
# This will default the database and logs location to be inside that directory.
dir = /var/www/ara/.ara
```

You'll be able to tell if this works by looking at the `/var/www/ara/.ara` directory -- you'll have an `ansible.sqlite` file created automatically when the application bootstraps itself.

This is the database that your user **and** Apache will need read and write access to. That's an exercise left to the reader since it's about filesystem permissions -- some users have created a common group containing `$USER` and `www-data`.